# Python Google Vision python script syntax errors

Tags: python

I am having some issues using the cloudvisreq python script for the Google Vision Python API. I get this error when I run the code:

```
File "newvisreq.py", line 46
    api_key, *image_filenames = argv[1:]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running the script through Python2.7, as it told me to in the tutorial I'm using to set this up. I found when I ran it through Python3 it was slightly more successful, as it managed to write as it was supposed to, but it received no data. The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/a0b69c84ebc00c54c94d/raw/2850e03ea92190114973f1064840783bfe026736/cloudvisreq.py), and the line the error complains about is about half way through the file (line 46).

Thanks in advance,

Connor

Comment: This is a feature of `python-3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This advanced form of *iterable unpacking* ([**PEP-3132**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)), is only available from [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (and further versions). You can however use the following code to make it equivalent:

```
api_key = argv[1]
image_filenames = argv[2:]
```

In case `argv` is *not a list* (if it is imported from `sys`, it is a list), you can use:

```
api_key = argv[1]
image_filenames = list(argv[2:])
```